# Gmail on OSX Right Click

Tags: safari, macos, google-chrome, gmail

Gmail is showing me this menu instead of the regular right-click menu. Particularly, I need "Open in Tab" for individual mails.

[image]

How do I get back to the "regular" Chrome/Safari right-click menu?

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-Click (aka right click) is context sensitive meaning it changes depending on where it is.  As such, lots of web apps (such as gmail) now utilize the right click for their own menu.  The easiest way to open this in a new tab is to hold `Cmd` and click the link; it will be automatic.  Holding `Shift` while clicking opens in a new window.

Comment: @allan `Cmd` absolutely works, and I thank you for that. However I'd love to know if this is new functionality in Gmail or if there's a way to step around it and get the "regular" menu back. Looks like it's new in Gmail and quite recent... but maybe not. Thanks!

Comment: I gave up Gmail along time ago so I can't confirm that, however, in Outlook.com it's been the same thing - I get a right-click menu on the web app like I do in the full blown Outlook client.  I don't know that you can force the old menu since it's context sensitive meaning it changes depending on what app you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Allan if I don't get any other answers I'd be forced to accept yours (if it were made into an answer). I'll keep hoping, but cmd-click isn't bad really. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the [contextual menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu) (activated by <kbd>Control</kbd> Click or "Right-Click") because it's embedded within the App; this includes the HTML code of a web page.

From [Apple's Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingContextualMenuItems/AddingContextualMenuItems.html)

> Contextual menus pop up when the user Control-clicks or right-clicks
>   over an object. Safari presents different contextual menus when the
>   mouse pointer is over the toolbar, Bookmarks bar, an extension bar,
>   the tab bar, or the contents of a webpage.
>
> Your extension can add menu items to the contextual menu that pops up
>   over web content. **You control the actions of the menu item by
>   installing a listener function for the "command" event in either your
>   global HTML page** or in an extension bar.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Essentially, what this is saying is that the **developer** of the (web) app sets the contents of the contextual menu.  If they don't set it, it will be the default for whatever is set in Safari/Chrome/Firefox/etc.

If your goal is to open a link in a new tab, hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while clicking to bypass the menu.  Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking opens the link in a new window.  I have found these options quicker than right clicking as my left hand rarely leaves the keyboard and I don't have to parse through a menu to find the item I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bookmarklet to disable non-native contextual menu.

Add this code as a bookmark addres:

```
javascript:(function(w){
var arr = ['contextmenu'];
for(var i = 0, x; x = arr[i]; i++){
    if(w['on' + x])w['on' + x] = null;
    w.addEventListener(x, function(e){e.stopPropagation()}, true);
};
for(var j = 0, f; f = w.frames[j]; j++){try{arguments.callee(f)}catch(e){}}})(window);
```

You'll need to "open" it whenever you want to disable the non-native contextual menu. Maybe there's some way of launching this atomatically, but I don't know how to do it.

Code taken from this [StackOverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12819640/3488699)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at the SO answer too... perhaps a tampermonkey with this code would do...

Comment: Thanks, this is very cool but ultimately I believe that Gmail has changed the options so that even with this the click menu is not available. This does suppress the app-specific right-click menu, though, so thanks for that.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say that the right-click-menu item, open in tab, isn't available.